# How to print result of a command as well as the count of results?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tee, process-substitution

I have to print all files containing a query given as a console argument, the following line does so

```
find . "$path" -type f -name "*$key*" -print
```

however I would also like to get the total file count, but doing this:

```
find . "$path" -type f -name "*$key*" -print | wc -l
```

will give me the count but not the names of those files, which isn't a desired result. How to fix it with a one liner (if possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the command [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) duplicating the output of the pipe and Bash‘s [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) as a placeholder for the file to provide the duplicated stream to `wc`:

```
$ seq 11 15 | tee >(wc -l)
11
12
13
14
15
5
```

Comment: @cyrus I think the key part of the answer is tee, not proc sub, since you can do it just as easily with a pipe.

Comment: You can show the different roads with `seq 11 15 | tee >(wc -l | sed 's/.*/Count results: &/' >&2) | sed 's/.*/Result: &/'`.